# Traceview cannot open from DDMS in eclipse

Tags: android, adt, ddms, android-traceview

today I use DDMS as usual, but there is a error - it cannot show me the trace report, the trace view canot open, exception infos as follows, it's very strange, because it's OK some days ago. my android version is 4.0.3, eclipse 3.7, ADT 21, Mac OSX 10.7.5, any one has the same error

[image]

[image]

Unable to create editor ID com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.editors.TraceviewEditor: Method exit (android/os/Debug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z) does not match current method (dalvik/system/VMDebug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method exit (android/os/Debug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z) does not match current method (dalvik/system/VMDebug.isMethodTracingActive ()Z)
    at com.android.traceview.ThreadData.exit(ThreadData.java:106)
    at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.parseData(DmTraceReader.java:323)
    at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.generateTrees(DmTraceReader.java:92)
    at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.<init>(DmTraceReader.java:87)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.editors.TraceviewEditor.createPartControl(TraceviewEditor.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1155)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.TraceviewLauncher$1.run(TraceviewLauncher.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3938)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: Try to updating your ADT plug in and related tools...

Comment: yes, I have tried, update ADT from 18 to 21, but error still

Comment: I'm getting the same error, on Win 7,Eclipse Indigo, Android version 4.0.3.. will be glad if anyone could answer

Answer (score 2):

Do you run your app inside Intel x86 Emulator image?

If yes, this might be the reason. At least I just was bitten by this error, but when I tried to repeat profiling inside an ARM based emulator image all went well, everything works there!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm running on a device, not emulator. Tried updating ADT plugin, still no use :(

Comment: I figured it was the problem with the device, not eclipse or ddms. I changed the device and traceview works perfectly fine.

Comment: Was it the x86 based device? :)

Comment: That was just the right hint - when running on an ARM based smartphone it just worked fine!